# Чтение и запись в файл с заменой символа

Tags: c++, файлы

Добрый день. Необходим пример чтения из одного файла и записи в другой файл. Причём все вхождения `\n` (символ новой строки) нужно заменить на  (пробел).

Answer (score 1):

```
ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");
string line;
while (getline(in, line)) {
    out << line << ' ';
}
```

Comment: А проверку: если встречается символ, то заменить его на другой, как реализовать? Что-то типо Contatains нужно, но как заменить

Comment: Может быть добавить строчку `replace(line.begin(), line.end(), 'x', 'y');` перед `out << line;`? Здесь `x` — символ, который заменяете, `y` — символ на который заменяете. [Описание функции replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace).

Comment: Поидее эта функция должна заменять символ '\n' на ' ': replace(line.begin(), line.end(), '\n', '\t');
Но, у меня получается, что пробелы не проставляются, но переход на новую строку пропадает.

Comment: @J.Defenses, обновил ответ.

Comment: @J.Defenses, функция [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) считывает ровно одну строку, причём строка получается без символа `\n`.

Comment: А как сделать replace  для замены пробела на сплошной текст, ругается на: 
`replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ' ', '');` 
Или к примеру: 
`replace(line.begin(), line.end(), '  ', ' ');`

Comment: Replace же принимается только Char, а двойной пробел - не char, как в этой ситуации быть?

Comment: Да, функция `replace` из комментария выше умеет заменять только символы. Для замены подстрок нужно написать свою функцию. [Вот](https://gist.github.com/dima74/64a90035aeed0f5fc754279b03b8d313), например, моя реализация.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");

char from = '\n', to = ' ', c;  // Подставьте свою замену...

while(in.get(c)) out.put((с == from) ? to : c);
```